# XAML Windows: How to trigger animations of a slider

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I think this code should be correct but the animation never starts. When the canvas is loaded I'd like the slider to go ahead until its maximum and then on reverse direction. I'm using Visual Studio.

```
    <Canvas>        
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                            From="50" To="100" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger> 
    </Canvas.Triggers>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider" Width="300" Height="30"
            Maximum="100" Minimum="50"/>
   </Canvas>
```

Comment: are you doing some code behind?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you know the possible causes?

Comment: There are some components but they are just textblock, some bindings between values and nothing else

Comment: i mean this xaml working with me without problem, so i asked if you change any thing on slider or bind something.

Comment: yes, there is a text whith a binding to the slider's value

Comment: so Make the bind on OneWay

Comment: Tried but still not working

Comment: put your code behind

Comment: I deleted everything but this block doesn't work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69223/discussion-between-safi-and-user3290180).